# How can I update a VersionOne asset using JSON and the rest-1.v1 API endpoint?

Tags: versionone

The default format for GET and POST operations against [rest-1.v1/Data](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Concepts/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData) and similar endpoints in VersionOne is XML.

Can I GET or POST updates of an Asset using JSON instead?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, can use JSON, with a couple of tweaks, and this caveat: **this feature is not officially documented or supported, so it's subject to changes at any time in new releases.**

To try the following examples, use `admin` / `admin` for the credentials.

## How to GET an Asset as JSON

There are two ways to tell VersionOne to send you back JSON.

### Method 1: Using an `accept=application/json` URL parameter

https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Issue/79242?**accept=application/json**&sel=Name,Description

The URL parameter `accept=application/json` tells VersionOne to send back JSON instead of XML for the selected `Name` and `Description` attributes for the specified Issue Asset.

### Method 2: Using an `Accept: application/json` HTTP header

You can also use the standard `Accept: application/json` header. You can try this out on the http.html page that's included with any VersionOne instance:

1. Open https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/http.html
2. URL field: `rest-1.v1/Data/Issue/79242?sel=Name,Description`
3. Accept field: `application/json`
4. Press the `GET` button

The raw HTTP format of this query should look something like this:

`GET /v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Issue/79242?sel=Name,Description HTTP/1.1
Host: www14.v1host.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json`

You should get back a result like:
`200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
VersionOne: Ultimate/16.0.3.233; Scrum
Content-Length: 252`

{
  "_type": "Asset",
  "href": "/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Issue/79242",
  "id": "Issue:79242",
  "Attributes": {
    "Name": {
      "_type": "Attribute",
      "name": "Name",
      "value": "Adam Martin"
    },
    "Description": {
      "_type": "Attribute",
      "name": "Description",
      "value": "Adam's description"
    }
  }
}

## How to POST (update) an Asset using JSON

To update an attribute for an Asset using JSON instead of XML, you add a `Content-Type: application/json` header to your HTTP request, and use the required JSON format.

Here's an example of modifying the same Asset from above:

1. Open https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/http.html
2. URL field: `rest-1.v1/Data/Issue/79242?sel=Name,Description`
3. Accept field: `application/json`
4. Content-Type field: `application/json`
5. Payload field:

   `{ 
       "Attributes": {
           "Description": {
               "value": "New value from the internet",
               "act": "set"
           }
       }
   }`
6. Press the `POST` button

You should get back a result like:

`200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
VersionOne: Ultimate/16.0.3.233; Scrum
Content-Length: 210`

{
    "_type": "Asset",
    "href": "/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Issue/79242/114699",
    "id": "Issue:79242:114699",
    "Attributes": {
        "Description": {
            "_type": "Attribute",
            "name": "Description",
            "value": "New value from the internet"
        }
    }
}

### Using cURL from the command line

If you have [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) installed, you can test this with this command:

`curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" \
   -H "Accept:application/json" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -d \
'{ 
  "Attributes": {
    "Description": {
      "value": "Newer value from the internet",
      "act": "set"
    }
  }
}' \
 'https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Issue/79242?sel=Name%2CDescription'`

### Important notes

- The resulting body that comes back will be formatted according to the value of the `Accept:` header, so you could actually get back XML if you really wanted by changing that!
- The body that comes back **does not match** the attributes in the `?sel=Name,Description` URL, but rather *only the attributes* that you actually modified in your POST.
- Be sure you specify the `"act": "set"` property in the attribute and not just the `"value": "some new value..."`. If you fail to do this, you will still get back a `200` result, but you will not see the values you modified.

Answer (score 2):

May be worth noting that when issuing an HTTP POST, with the Content-Type Header set to application/json, to the `rest-1.v1/` endpoint and attempting to update a multi-value relation the following format is used:
`<versionone-url>/rest-1.v1/Story`
`{ 
    "Attributes": {
        "ChangeSets": {
            "name": "ChangeSets",
            "value": [
                { "idref": "ChangeSet:1234", "act": "add" },
                { "idref": "ChangeSet:3456", "act": "add" }
            ]
        }
    }
}`